# parse JSON javascript in Node-Red

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

I have parsed JSON before in C# but this time I am going to use JavaScript in Node-Red.
I have searched the web and find several solution to parse JSON with JavaScript but in all example the JSON was very simple and not many "level" of data in it.

I will provide a small part of the JSON file that i need to parse

```
{
"programStatus": {
"modified_host_attributes": "1",
"modified_service_attributes": "1",
"serial_host_check_stats": "0,0,0"
},
"hosts": {
"FILANAS01": {
  "host_name": "FILANAS01",
  "modified_attributes": "0",
  "check_command": "check-host-alive",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
},
"FILANAS02": {
  "host_name": "FILANAS02",
  "modified_attributes": "0",
  "check_command": "check-host-alive",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
},
"FILANSW01": {
  "host_name": "FILANSW01",
  "modified_attributes": "0",
  "check_command": "check-host-alive",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
},
"FILANSW02": {
  "host_name": "FILANSW02",
  "modified_attributes": "0",
  "check_command": "check-host-alive",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
}
},
"services": {
"FILANSW01": {
"HP ProCurve Hardware Check": {
  "host_name": "FILANSW01",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
},
"System Location": {
  "host_name": "FILANSW01",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
}
},
"FILANSW02": {
"HP ProCurve Hardware Check": {
  "host_name": "FILANSW02",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
},
"System Location": {
  "host_name": "FILANSW02",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
}
},
"FILASDC02": {
"Active Directory Domain Services": {
  "host_name": "FILASDC02",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
},
"CPU Load": {
  "host_name": "FILASDC02",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
},
"DNS Server": {
  "host_name": "FILASDC02",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
},
"Drive Space C:": {
  "host_name": "FILASDC02",
  "current_state": "0",
  "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This is generated from Nagios and it contains servers and switches and information about them.
I need to iterate through all "hosts" and see what "current_state" is, if its something else then 0 then i will fetch the "host_name" and some other information from that "host".

And the same thing from "services" check current state if its not 0.

I will then create an array with the information i have fetched from this JSON and present it on a information screen.

But i need some help to get started with the JSON.
Thanks.

Comment: JSON.parse(yourJsonData) should have been enough but your data is a bulky javascript object which could have been an array of object.

Comment: It is not possible to loop over `hosts` without knowing the `keys`. It would have been very easy if `hosts` and `services` were `array` which should be ideallly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Assign the entire JSON in a JavaScript variable, complete code shown below:
```

`
               var myJSON = {
                "programStatus": {
                    "modified_host_attributes": "1",
                    "modified_service_attributes": "1",
                    "serial_host_check_stats": "0,0,0"
                },
                "hosts": {
                    "FILANAS01": {
                        "host_name": "FILANAS01",
                        "modified_attributes": "0",
                        "check_command": "check-host-alive",
                        "current_state": "0",
                        "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                    },
                    "FILANAS02": {
                        "host_name": "FILANAS02",
                        "modified_attributes": "0",
                        "check_command": "check-host-alive",
                        "current_state": "0",
                        "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                    },
                    "FILANSW01": {
                        "host_name": "FILANSW01",
                        "modified_attributes": "0",
                        "check_command": "check-host-alive",
                        "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                    },
                    "FILANSW02": {
                        "host_name": "FILANSW02",
                        "modified_attributes": "0",
                        "check_command": "check-host-alive",
                        "current_state": "0",
                        "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                    }
                },
                "services": {
                    "FILANSW01": {
                        "HP ProCurve Hardware Check": {
                            "host_name": "FILANSW01",
                            "current_state": "0",
                            "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                        },
                        "System Location": {
                            "host_name": "FILANSW01",
                            "current_state": "0",
                            "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    "FILANSW02": {
                        "HP ProCurve Hardware Check": {
                            "host_name": "FILANSW02",
                            "current_state": "0",
                            "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                        },
                        "System Location": {
                            "host_name": "FILANSW02",
                            "current_state": "0",
                            "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    "FILASDC02": {
                        "Active Directory Domain Services": {
                            "host_name": "FILASDC02",
                            "current_state": "0",
                            "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                        },
                        "CPU Load": {
                            "host_name": "FILASDC02",
                            "current_state": "0",
                            "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                        },
                        "DNS Server": {
                            "host_name": "FILASDC02",
                            "current_state": "0",
                            "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                        },
                        "Drive Space C:": {
                            "host_name": "FILASDC02",
                            "current_state": "0",
                            "scheduled_downtime_depth": "0"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

```
Now iterate through:

var host = Object.keys(myJSON["hosts"]);
for (var i = 0; i < host.length; i++) {
      var hostData = host[i];
      var hostProp = myJSON.hosts[hostData];
      if (hostProp.current_state != 0) {
           //Do your work.
      } 
}
I've tested Object.keys() in a few browsers like IE9, IE10, Chrome 46
and FireFox, it works but fails in IE8.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
This is the error message i get when i try this code:
Object.keys(myJSON["hosts"]); ^ Object.keys called on non-object

Comment: That error suggests you've set myJSON to the raw JSON string. You need to parse it to an object first: `var myJSON = JSON.parse(myJSONString);`